# Regular expression to match all content including unicode punctuation mark

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I am trying to match some text which may include unicode characters including special punctuation marks like  (`\u0085` in Java).

When I do something like

```
Matcher testMatcher = Pattern.compile("(.+)", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).matcher("test text up \u0085 after");
```

I get a match of "test text up", without the punctuation mark, however I would like to match all content. How do I do this?

See also a [demonstration in the regex101 tool](https://regex101.com/r/jM7zY6/1).

Update: I did try `((?:\P{M}\p{M}*+)+)` [as discussed at regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), but it does not seem to work in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol belongs to *Cc - Other, control* category.

You need to add the `Pattern.DOTALL` modifier to match it. Or append `(?s)` at the pattern start.

> General category:                Cc - Other, control
>   Canonical combining class:  0 - Spacing, split, enclosing, reordrant, & Tibetan subjoined
>   Bidirectional category:          B - Paragraph separator
>   Unicode 1.0 name:                 **NEXT LINE (NEL)**
>
>   Unicode version:                     1.1
>   As text:    
>   Decimal:    133
>   HTML escape:                          …
>   URL escape:                         %C2%85

See [details here](http://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%C2%85#title)

And here is an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/LiCDJr)

```
Matcher testMatcher = Pattern.compile(".+", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).matcher("test text up \u0085 after");
if (testMatcher.find()){
    System.out.println(testMatcher.group(0)); 
} // => test text up  after
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to solve the general case, however I found one case that still fails:         
testMatcher = Pattern.compile("(.+?)\\s+a", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).matcher("some other text \u0085 a");
        assertTrue(testMatcher.find());
        assertEquals("some other text \u0085", testMatcher.group(1));

It seems here the `\s` somehow breaks the match.

Comment: It does not break the match, just `(.+?)` only matches up to the *first whitespace symbol*, but you compare it with a string that ends with a whitespace. See [demo](http://ideone.com/pdGj4y). So, it is a problem with the test case.